# Why is my cron command not outputting in log file?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, cron, raspberry-pi, debian

On my raspberry pi, I have entered the following entry in my crontab using crontab -e (without sudo):

```
* * * * * echo "Hello World" &>> /home/pi/test.txt
```

Just as a test, that is.

After restarting cron (sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart) the test.txt file is created in /home/pi/, but the content remains empty.

Why?

If I run this without the asterisks in my ssh terminal on the Rasberry Pi, it works fine.

I got to this point because my goal is to run a python script and log any errors, because sometimes it stops running and I don't know why. Hence my need for logging.

Thank you for your help!

P.S. I have the same problem on my Orange Pi that runs Raspbian (Debian Buster), but there cron doesn't work for some reason so there I am using rc.local to run my scripts on boot. But the same problem arises: Log file is created but no content is added.

Comment: What do you think `&>>` is doing?

Comment: Append stderr and stdout to the file specified after. Same as ```command >> file.txt 2>&1```

Comment: Although I have solved my problem by using systemctl instead, I am still curious for the answer...

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Raspbian is using `dash` as the default shell for cron. `dash` is `sh` compliant and not `bash` compliant. That means that you cannot use `&>>`. You must use `>> output.log 2>&1` instead.

You're saying that your goal is to run a Python script. There's a catch with that too. Python's buffering output so if it's too short it won't appear in your log file by default. You can use `python -u` for unbuffered output.

I hope that my answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * * * python /home/pi/code.py 2>&1 /home/pi/code.log
```

Hello, the last part of the above snippet in the crontab will write every log in the file /home/pi/code.log

Hope it helps